# Linq progressive state based query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Firstly apologies for the poor title. Absolutely no idea how to describe this question!

I have a "Relationship" entity that defines a relationship between 2 users.

```
public class Relationship{
 User User1{get;set;}
 User User2{get;set;}
 DateTime StateChangeDate {get;set;}

 //RelationshipState is an Enum with int values
 State RelationshipState State{get;set;}
}
```

Relationship state example.

```
public enum RelationshipState{
 state1 = 1,
 state2 = 2, 
 state3 = 3,
 state4 = 4
}
```

A Relationship entity is created each time the RelationshipState changes. So for any pair of users, there will be many Relationship objects. With the most recent being current.

I'm trying to query for any Relationship object that represents a REDUCTION in RelationshipState for a particular pair of users.

So all the RelationshipObjects for all the users. That have a later Date than one with a higher RelationshipState.

I'm finding it very hard to figure out how to accomplish this without iterating over the entire Relationship table.

Comment: Some code examples of any attempts with actual data and expected results will be very suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a query to return all the combinations of users and a child that lists all the status changes.  For more information, google LINQ Group By.

Then using your collection, filter out all the ones you don't want by looking at the last two status changes and seeing if it's gone down.

Here's an example, tested in LinqPad as a C# Program:

```
public enum RelationshipState {
 state1 = 1,
 state2 = 2, 
 state3 = 3,
 state4 = 4
}
public class User {
   public int id {get;set;}
}
public class Relationship{
 public User User1{get;set;}
 public User User2{get;set;}
 public DateTime StateChangeDate {get;set;}

 //RelationshipState is an Enum with int values
 public RelationshipState State {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{


var rs=new List<Relationship>() {
 new Relationship{ User1=new User{id=1},User2=new User{id=2},StateChangeDate=DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013"),State=RelationshipState.state2},
 new Relationship{ User1=new User{id=1},User2=new User{id=2},StateChangeDate=DateTime.Parse("1/2/2013"),State=RelationshipState.state3},
 new Relationship{ User1=new User{id=1},User2=new User{id=3},StateChangeDate=DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013"),State=RelationshipState.state2},
 new Relationship{ User1=new User{id=1},User2=new User{id=3},StateChangeDate=DateTime.Parse("1/2/2013"),State=RelationshipState.state1},
 new Relationship{ User1=new User{id=2},User2=new User{id=3},StateChangeDate=DateTime.Parse("1/2/3013"),State=RelationshipState.state1}
};

var result=rs.GroupBy(cm=>new {id1=cm.User1.id,id2=cm.User2.id},(key,group)=>new {Key1=key,Group1=group.OrderByDescending(g=>g.StateChangeDate)})
 .Where(r=>r.Group1.Count()>1) // Remove Entries with only 1 status
 //.ToList() // This might be needed for Linq-to-Entities
 .Where(r=>r.Group1.First().State<r.Group1.Skip(1).First().State) // Only keep relationships where the state has gone done
 .Select(r=>r.Group1.First())  //Turn this back into Relationship objects
 ;

// Use this instead if you want to know if state ever had a higher state than it is currently
//  var result=rs.GroupBy(cm=>new {id1=cm.User1.id,id2=cm.User2.id},(key,group)=>new {Key1=key,Group1=group.OrderByDescending(g=>g.StateChangeDate)})
//   .Where(r=>r.Group1.First().State<r.Group1.Max(g=>g.State))
//   .Select(r=>r.Group1.First())
//   ;

result.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic response. Didn't require the ToList. I hadn't thought about moving the group it's self around. I was trying to do it with subqueries. This is far better

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure in the database that can use a cursor to iterate the items and pair them off with the item before them (and then filter to decreasing state.)

Barring that, you can perform an inner query that finds the previous value for each item:

```
from item in table
let previous = 
    (from innerItem in table 
    where previous.date < item.Date 
    select innerItem)
    .Max(inner => inner.Date)
where previous.State > item.State
select item
```

As inefficient as that seems, It might be worth a try.  Perhaps, with the proper indexes, and a good query optimizer (and a sufficiently small set of data) it won't be that bad.  If it's unacceptably slow, then trying out a stored proc with a cursor is most likely going to be the best.